# Filter data according to today's date and specific time range

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula, autofilter

I have a set of data that refreshed everyday on my excel sheet.
I need to automatically filter the system date to today's date on column E and system time on column F between time of 0730 till 1930 via excel VBA daily.
How should I do this?

I have tried using

```
Sub DateNTimeFilter()

Dim DateToday As Date
DateToday = Today()

Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E").Autofilter Field=5, Operator:=x1Filtervalues, Criteria:=TodayDate
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Please include it in your question.

Comment: Added in. Please advise. I am a novice.

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Any errors? If so in which line? • Note that  `Range("E1:E")` is not a valid address and therefore cannot work. • Did you try the Macro Recoder to see how the code would look like?

Comment: And you're declaring a `Dim DateToday As Date`, but trying to use another thing `Criteria:=TodayDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code you posted.

All cleaned up it should look something like this:

```
Sub DateNTimeFilter()

Sheet1.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Format(Date,"dd/mm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

First of all `Today()` isn't a standard VBA function unless you've coded one. Use `Date` instead.

You also dim `DateToday`, but use `TodayDate` in your autofilter.

You also start your autofilter twice, once for the selection, once for your activesheet rangeE1:E. The first bit is redundant, so it can be left out.

Your range `E1:E` is an incorrect range, either use `E:E` or leave it out altogether. Since you use `field:=5` already indicating column 5 (E).

You misspelled `xlFilterValues`, and forgot to specify `Criteria1` as you always need to specify criteria 1 or 2.

If all you're using is todays date, no calculations need to be made, so you can insert this directly into your autofilter. The only thing I would add is a `format` statement to clean it up and match the way your dates are written.

**EDIT:** To add start and end times to this is a bit more challenging than this, but the below should do it.

```
Sub DateNTimeFilter()
Dim in_time As Double, out_time As Double

in_time = Date + TimeValue("07:30")
out_time = Date + TimeValue("19:30")

Sheet1.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=">=" & in_time, Criteria2:="<=" & out_time

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right sir! Thank you it works as you said! 
How do I then write the code to filter the timing between 0730-1930? How do I set 2 criteria and what format should the time be?

Comment: To work with adding times to dates is a bit more finicky. I've updated my answer.

Comment: My dates are on Column E and times are on Column F so can be AutoFilter Field be both 5 and 6?

Comment: In that case it's best to run two separate autofilters after each other. First with field 5 for your date as my original answer, second with field 6 as my edit with criteria like so: `Criteria1:=">=" & TimeValue("07:30")`

Comment: Right now my code is Sub DateNTimeFilter()

    Dim DateToday As Date

    DateToday = Date
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Range("F1:F1").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & TimeValue("07:30"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=<" & TimeValue("19:30")
    

End Sub

Comment: And my data are 07:29:00 AM
07:31:00 AM
08:30:00 AM
10:00:22 AM
11:00:15 AM
01:59:56 PM
03:01:40 PM
04:02:58 PM
06:03:28 PM
07:04:10 PM
08:04:36 PM

Comment: But the code filtered all the timings away, I am really baffled.

Comment: If you set your formatting in your time cell to "general", you'll see the value is actually a several digit number. This is how excel calculates dates and times. As long as you match it to a variable holding a proper time it will work, no matter how it is displayed. The issue is if you set it to general and it doesn't change, it is then stored as text and a lot harder to work with.